# codeigniter htaccess file in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, nginx

I did a project in codeigniter. 
It worked perfect in localhost.
The htaccess file in localhost:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Then i removed the project to hosting to subdomain college.utest.kz
But it did not work on the internet. Changed the htaccess file content as in codeigniter documentation. The result is the same
Thank you for reading

Comment: Which server you can use like linux,window etc

Comment: @ChauhanShailesh linux

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: in browser it shows not found page. 
In log file there is written: `[error] 32412#0: *4993796 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.97.115.34, server: college.utest.kz, request: "GET /college.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/college.utest.kz.sock:", host: "college.utest.kz"`

Comment: Can you give me live url ? If possible

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots  \.txt|favicon\.ico)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you. but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdomain_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Use your subdomain folder name rewrite base